# Script that retrieves urls of rss feeds. Use urllib2/beautifulsoup. Store urls in a list

Tags: python, parsing, rss, beautifulsoup

Create a script that retrieves all urls of rss feeds from http://www.volkskrant.nl/nl/2764/rss/integration/nmc/frameset/footer/rss/rssFeeds.dhtml. Use urllib2 and beautifulsoup for this. Store the urls in a list.

**What I have so far is this, but I don´t know how to proceed:**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req= urllib2.Request('http://www.volkskrant.nl/nl/2764/rss/integration/nmc/frameset/footer/rss/rssFeeds.dhtml')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)

print (soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `soup.find_all` method inside a list comprehension.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> req= urllib2.Request('http://www.volkskrant.nl/nl/2764/rss/integration/nmc/frameset/footer/rss/rssFeeds.dhtml')
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> the_page = response.read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
>>> [i['href'] for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
['http://www.google.be', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/nieuws-voorpagina/', '#site-nav', '#login', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/', '/buitenland/leiders-sharia4belgium-veroordeeld-tot-jaren-cel~a3849141/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849141&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/vvd-kamerlid-declareerde-onterecht-duizenden-euros~a3849244/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849244&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-wikileaks/manning-vanuit-gevangenis-nieuwe-columnist-guardian~a3849172/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849172&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849219&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/buitenland/dag-van-de-waarheid-voor-europa~a3849112/', '/buitenland/dag-van-de-waarheid-voor-europa~a3849112/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849112&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/dag-van-de-waarheid-voor-europa~a3849112/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/buitenland/', '/dossier-oorlog-in-oekraine/live-onderhandelingen-minsk-kunnen-beginnen~a3849093/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849093&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-oorlog-in-oekraine/alles-gereed-voor-topoverleg-minsk~a3849085/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849085&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/om-kapitein-costa-concordia-had-slachtoffers-kunnen-redden~a3849195/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849195&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/dag-van-de-waarheid-voor-europa~a3849112/', '/buitenland/dag-van-de-waarheid-voor-europa~a3849112/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849112&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/dag-van-de-waarheid-voor-europa~a3849112/', '/buitenland/nu-of-nooit-dat-ziet-poetin-helemaal-niet-zo~a3848775/', '/buitenland/nu-of-nooit-dat-ziet-poetin-helemaal-niet-zo~a3848775/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848775&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/nu-of-nooit-dat-ziet-poetin-helemaal-niet-zo~a3848775/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/binnenland/', '/binnenland/opnieuw-dodelijke-schietpartij-in-amsterdam~a3849054/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849054&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/vvd-kamerlid-declareerde-onterecht-duizenden-euros~a3849244/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849244&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/medewerkers-nrc-willen-flinke-bonus-egeria~a3849218/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849218&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849219&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/politiek/binnenskamers-win-win-win-scenario-voor-groningen~a3848634/', '/politiek/binnenskamers-win-win-win-scenario-voor-groningen~a3848634/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848634&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/politiek/binnenskamers-win-win-win-scenario-voor-groningen~a3848634/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/opinie/', '/opinie/dagvaarden-meijering-door-om-was-terecht~a3849232/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849232&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/opinie/circustijger-en-tijger-in-dierentuin-zijn-dezelfde~a3848748/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848748&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/opinie/wordt-het-wat-met-denk~a3848565/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848565&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-stekel/aardgas-en-verkiezingen~a3848702/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848702&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-stekel/aardgas-en-verkiezingen~a3848702/', '/dossier-max-pam/allemaal-de-schuld-van-het-openbaar-ministerie~a3848722/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848722&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-max-pam/allemaal-de-schuld-van-het-openbaar-ministerie~a3848722/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/economie/', '/binnenland/medewerkers-nrc-willen-flinke-bonus-egeria~a3849218/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849218&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/economie/ing-keert-weer-winst-uit~a3849079/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849079&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/media/persgroep-mag-wegener-overnemen~a3849241/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849241&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/leven/mijn-ontslag-voltrok-zich-te-geleidelijk-om-kwaad-te-worden~a3849105/', '/leven/mijn-ontslag-voltrok-zich-te-geleidelijk-om-kwaad-te-worden~a3849105/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849105&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/leven/mijn-ontslag-voltrok-zich-te-geleidelijk-om-kwaad-te-worden~a3849105/', '/economie/prima-ingeschaald-tel-je-zegeningen~a3848732/', '/economie/prima-ingeschaald-tel-je-zegeningen~a3848732/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848732&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/economie/prima-ingeschaald-tel-je-zegeningen~a3848732/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/sport/', '/sport/verweij-zoekt-goud-op-vrijdag-de-dertiende-zit-tegen-mijn-topvorm~a3849217/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849217&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/sport/dopingautoriteit-bevestigt-doping-bij-topklasser-spakenburg~a3849274/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849274&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/sport/dopingautoriteit-bevestigt-doping-in-kleedkamer-spakenburg~a3849225/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849225&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/sport/hangen-en-wurgen-in-de-laatste-binnenbocht~a3848771/', '/sport/hangen-en-wurgen-in-de-laatste-binnenbocht~a3848771/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848771&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/sport/hangen-en-wurgen-in-de-laatste-binnenbocht~a3848771/', '/sport/ik-had-mijn-racket-bijna-verruild-voor-een-geweer~a3848786/', '/sport/ik-had-mijn-racket-bijna-verruild-voor-een-geweer~a3848786/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848786&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/sport/ik-had-mijn-racket-bijna-verruild-voor-een-geweer~a3848786/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/tech/', '/dossier-wikileaks/manning-vanuit-gevangenis-nieuwe-columnist-guardian~a3849172/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849172&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/tech/apps-zijn-net-zo-slordig-als-stappentellers~a3848710/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848710&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/tech/cybercaliphate-hackt-newsweek-en-bedreigt-obamas~a3848582/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848582&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/meer-spionage-mogelijk-voor-inlichtingendiensten~a3848756/', '/binnenland/meer-spionage-mogelijk-voor-inlichtingendiensten~a3848756/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848756&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/meer-spionage-mogelijk-voor-inlichtingendiensten~a3848756/', '/tech/heeft-samsung-de-big-brother-tv-gemaakt~a3848620/', '/tech/heeft-samsung-de-big-brother-tv-gemaakt~a3848620/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848620&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/tech/heeft-samsung-de-big-brother-tv-gemaakt~a3848620/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/media/', '/dossier-wikileaks/manning-vanuit-gevangenis-nieuwe-columnist-guardian~a3849172/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849172&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/medewerkers-nrc-willen-flinke-bonus-egeria~a3849218/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849218&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/media/jon-stewart-stopt-in-de-zomer-met-the-daily-show~a3849087/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849087&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/media/tv-serie-de-fractie-is-altijd-een-act~a3848652/', '/media/tv-serie-de-fractie-is-altijd-een-act~a3848652/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848652&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/media/tv-serie-de-fractie-is-altijd-een-act~a3848652/', '/dossier-tv-tips/kunststof-zembla-life-story~a3848635/', '/dossier-tv-tips/kunststof-zembla-life-story~a3848635/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848635&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-tv-tips/kunststof-zembla-life-story~a3848635/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/wetenschap/', '/wetenschap/hip-record-166-stations-in-ruim-15-uur~a3848730/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848730&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/wetenschap/onbemande-ruimtecapsule-in-stille-oceaan-geland~a3849041/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849041&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/viool-muteerde-tot-krachtiger-instrument~a3848729/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848729&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/economie/prima-ingeschaald-tel-je-zegeningen~a3848732/', '/economie/prima-ingeschaald-tel-je-zegeningen~a3848732/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848732&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/economie/prima-ingeschaald-tel-je-zegeningen~a3848732/', '/leven/heel-holland-mediteert~a3848743/', '/leven/heel-holland-mediteert~a3848743/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848743&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/leven/heel-holland-mediteert~a3848743/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/politiek/', '/binnenland/vvd-kamerlid-declareerde-onterecht-duizenden-euros~a3849244/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849244&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-kabinet-rutte-ii/samsom-gaswinning-na-juli-niet-weer-omhoog~a3848778/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848778&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/hennis-negeert-in-jsf-budget-kans-op-verongelukken-toestel~a3848712/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848712&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849219&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/kan-nederland-zomaar-de-gaskraan-dichtdraaien~a3849219/', '/politiek/binnenskamers-win-win-win-scenario-voor-groningen~a3848634/', '/politiek/binnenskamers-win-win-win-scenario-voor-groningen~a3848634/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848634&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/politiek/binnenskamers-win-win-win-scenario-voor-groningen~a3848634/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/specials/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/cartoons/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/foto/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/vonk/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/dag-in-dag-uit/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/cultuur-en-leven/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/cultuur-en-leven/', '/dossier-wikileaks/manning-vanuit-gevangenis-nieuwe-columnist-guardian~a3849172/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849172&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/media/jon-stewart-stopt-in-de-zomer-met-the-daily-show~a3849087/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849087&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/australie-doet-eenmalig-mee-aan-eurovisie-songfestival~a3849097/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849097&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/we-houden-meer-van-rust~a3849238/', '/muziek/we-houden-meer-van-rust~a3849238/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849238&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/we-houden-meer-van-rust~a3849238/', '/leven/mijn-ontslag-voltrok-zich-te-geleidelijk-om-kwaad-te-worden~a3849105/', '/leven/mijn-ontslag-voltrok-zich-te-geleidelijk-om-kwaad-te-worden~a3849105/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849105&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/leven/mijn-ontslag-voltrok-zich-te-geleidelijk-om-kwaad-te-worden~a3849105/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/agenda/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/recensies/', '/muziek/vrolijkmakende-popliedjes-in-jarenvijftigsfeer~a3843728/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3843728&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-musea-en-galerieen/kunstmusea-opnieuw-de-les-gelezen-met-advertentie~a3754052/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3754052&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/agenda/troostmeisjes-van-nederlandse-fotograaf-banning-nu-ook-te-zien-in-japan~a3752584/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3752584&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/recensies/napalm-death-klinkt-verfijnd-en-kunstzinnig~a3848758/', '/recensies/napalm-death-klinkt-verfijnd-en-kunstzinnig~a3848758/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848758&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/recensies/het-spelplezier-spat-ervan-af~a3848644/', '/recensies/het-spelplezier-spat-ervan-af~a3848644/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848644&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/film/', '/dossier-oscars/nederlandse-korte-animatiefilm-genomineerd-voor-oscar~a3830501/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3830501&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/film/kabelaars-overstag-16-miljoen-voor-auteursrechten-filmmakers~a3847796/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847796&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/film/bafta-award-voor-beste-film-naar-boyhood~a3847313/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847313&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-filmtips/al-pacino-in-film-die-volop-amuseert-maar-ook-karakterloos-aanvoelt~a3847881/', '/dossier-filmtips/al-pacino-in-film-die-volop-amuseert-maar-ook-karakterloos-aanvoelt~a3847881/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847881&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-filmtips/al-pacino-in-film-die-volop-amuseert-maar-ook-karakterloos-aanvoelt~a3847881/', '/film/steeds-meer-vrouwelijke-protagonisten-in-films~a3846374/', '/film/steeds-meer-vrouwelijke-protagonisten-in-films~a3846374/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3846374&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/film/steeds-meer-vrouwelijke-protagonisten-in-films~a3846374/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/muziek/', '/buitenland/australie-doet-eenmalig-mee-aan-eurovisie-songfestival~a3849097/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849097&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/viool-muteerde-tot-krachtiger-instrument~a3848729/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848729&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/faithless-komt-na-vier-jaar-alweer-samen~a3849270/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849270&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/we-houden-meer-van-rust~a3849238/', '/muziek/we-houden-meer-van-rust~a3849238/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3849238&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/muziek/we-houden-meer-van-rust~a3849238/', '/recensies/napalm-death-klinkt-verfijnd-en-kunstzinnig~a3848758/', '/recensies/napalm-death-klinkt-verfijnd-en-kunstzinnig~a3848758/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848758&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/reizen/', '/reizen/eerste-verre-bestemming-eindhoven-airport~a3847743/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847743&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/reizen/weer-toeriste-verkracht-in-india-politie-zoekt-verdachte-gids~a3847622/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847622&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/twee-nederlanders-verongelukt-in-thailand~a3845467/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3845467&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/reizen/de-voor-en-tegenstanders-van-apies-kijken~a3847261/', '/reizen/de-voor-en-tegenstanders-van-apies-kijken~a3847261/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847261&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/reizen/de-voor-en-tegenstanders-van-apies-kijken~a3847261/', '/reizen/ontdek-de-schoonheid-in-de-lelijkheid-van-keulen~a3845354/', '/reizen/ontdek-de-schoonheid-in-de-lelijkheid-van-keulen~a3845354/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3845354&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/reizen/ontdek-de-schoonheid-in-de-lelijkheid-van-keulen~a3845354/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/koken-en-eten/', '/koken-en-eten/antibioticaresistente-bacterien-op-helft-van-vis-en-garnalen~a3785000/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3785000&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/economie/sire-start-grote-campagne-tegen-voedselverspilling~a3848334/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848334&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/ontwerper-kikkoman-flesje-overleden~a3847715/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847715&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-volkskeuken/griesmeelpudding-met-vermout-en-granaatappel~a3848632/', '/dossier-volkskeuken/griesmeelpudding-met-vermout-en-granaatappel~a3848632/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848632&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-volkskeuken/griesmeelpudding-met-vermout-en-granaatappel~a3848632/', '/vonk/eerlijk-betaald-het-is-tijd-om-te-benoemen-wat-misgaat-niet-wat-goed-gaat~a3848380/', '/vonk/eerlijk-betaald-het-is-tijd-om-te-benoemen-wat-misgaat-niet-wat-goed-gaat~a3848380/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848380&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/vonk/eerlijk-betaald-het-is-tijd-om-te-benoemen-wat-misgaat-niet-wat-goed-gaat~a3848380/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/theater/', '/buitenland/geen-konzertsaal-in-munchen~a3844702/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3844702&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/dossier-dans/bng-prijs-voor-choreografe~a3843062/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3843062&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/leven/omstreden-grindr-theater-in-utrecht~a3838833/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3838833&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/theater/de-nieuwe-doelen-blijft-tijdelijk-open-dankzij-geld-gemeente~a3848738/', '/theater/de-nieuwe-doelen-blijft-tijdelijk-open-dankzij-geld-gemeente~a3848738/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848738&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/theater/de-nieuwe-doelen-blijft-tijdelijk-open-dankzij-geld-gemeente~a3848738/', '/recensies/fluisteropera-van-david-lang-is-magische-intieme-ervaring~a3848422/', '/recensies/fluisteropera-van-david-lang-is-magische-intieme-ervaring~a3848422/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848422&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/recensies/fluisteropera-van-david-lang-is-magische-intieme-ervaring~a3848422/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/boeken/', '/boeken/hannelore-grunberg-klein-87-moeder-arnon-grunberg-overleden~a3848498/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848498&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/schrijver-andre-brink-overleden-tijdens-klm-vlucht~a3846827/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3846827&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/boeken/twijfel-over-opvolger-to-kill-a-mocking-bird~a3844665/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3844665&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/boeken/moeder-van-arnon-grunberg-was-een-soldaat-zonder-uniform~a3848556/', '/boeken/moeder-van-arnon-grunberg-was-een-soldaat-zonder-uniform~a3848556/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848556&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/boeken/moeder-van-arnon-grunberg-was-een-soldaat-zonder-uniform~a3848556/', '/boeken/zwagermans-intense-jaren-negentig~a3847929/', '/boeken/zwagermans-intense-jaren-negentig~a3847929/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847929&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/boeken/zwagermans-intense-jaren-negentig~a3847929/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/beeldende-kunst/', '/dossier-musea-en-galerieen/schotse-kunst-ging-kelder-in~a3848735/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848735&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/tech/world-press-photo-wordt-denktank~a3847966/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847966&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/buitenland/elektricien-picasso-voor-heling-voor-rechter~a3847792/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847792&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/marjolijn-meynen-maakt-ons-gek-van-rembrandt~a3848011/', '/binnenland/marjolijn-meynen-maakt-ons-gek-van-rembrandt~a3848011/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3848011&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/binnenland/marjolijn-meynen-maakt-ons-gek-van-rembrandt~a3848011/', '/recensies/een-zwevend-nest-met-logge-kantoorkozijnen-en-systeemplafonds~a3847900/', '/recensies/een-zwevend-nest-met-logge-kantoorkozijnen-en-systeemplafonds~a3847900/', '/user/resource/save.do?resourceId=3847900&resourceType=ARTICLE&save=true', '#login', '/recensies/een-zwevend-nest-met-logge-kantoorkozijnen-en-systeemplafonds~a3847900/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/leven/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mode-en-mooi/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/festivals/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/televisie/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/voordeel/', '#user-nav', '#login', '#1', '#', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/nieuws/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/ik-volg/onderwerpen/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/lees-later/', '#logout', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/instellingen/', '/mijn-vk/instellingen/', '#logout', '#', '#login', '#login', '#login', '#logout', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/instellingen/', '#login', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/het-weer/', 'http://z24beurs.z24.nl/?PARTNER=vk', 'http://www.intermediair.nl/vacature/zoeken/overzicht/?ref=vkbanen.nl&utm_source=vk.nl&utm_medium=navigatie&utm_campaign=persgroep_netwerk&utm_term=lead&utm_content=vacature_zoeken', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/aboneerpagina-abc?otag=9f8ydb&utm_source=vk&utm_medium=tekstlink&utm_content=tekstlink+header&utm_campaign=abonneren', 'http://krant.volkskrant.nl', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/service', 'https://www.volkskrant.nl/shop/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/inclusief', 'https://twitter.com/volkskrant', 'https://www.facebook.com/volkskrant', 'http://shop.volkskrant.nl/product/volkskrant-filmfestival-2014', 'http://shop.volkskrant.nl/product/girls-3', 'https://www.volkskrant.nl/shop/', 'https://twitter.com/volkskrant', 'https://www.facebook.com/volkskrant', 'https://plus.google.com/+volkskrant/posts', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/archief/', 'http://krant.volkskrant.nl', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/redactie/', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/app#de_Volkskrant', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/app#de_Volkskrant_Digitale_Editie', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/app#de_Volkskrant_Select', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/app', 'http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Volkskrant', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/vk/nl/2764/auteursrecht/integration/nmc/frameset/varia/auteursrecht.dhtml', 'http://www.persgroep.nl/privacy', 'http://www.persgroep.nl/vacatures', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/productinformatie?otag=9f8ydb&utm_source=vk&utm_medium=tekstlink&utm_content=tekstlink+footer&utm_campaign=vk+info', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/vk/nl/2764/rss/integration/nmc/frameset/footer/rss/rssFeeds.dhtml', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/aboneerpagina-abc?otag=9f8ydb&utm_source=vk&utm_medium=tekstlink&utm_content=tekstlink+footer&utm_campaign=abonneren', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/service', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/integratie/meest-gestelde-vragen/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/integratie/contactgegevens/', 'http://www.persgroepadvertising.nl/onze-merken/het-merk-de-volkskrant?utm_source=volkskrant.nl&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=Adverteren%2BService%26Contact', 'http://depersgroep.nl/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/integratie/gebruiksvoorwaarden/', '#nieuws-subnav', '#cultuur-leven-subnav', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/het-weer/', 'http://z24beurs.z24.nl/?PARTNER=vk', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/nieuws-voorpagina/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/buitenland/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/binnenland/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/opinie/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/economie/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/sport/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/tech/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/media/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/wetenschap/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/politiek/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/specials/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/cartoons/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/foto/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/vonk/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/dag-in-dag-uit/', 'http://volkskrant.kranten.nl/?utm_source=volkskrant.nl&utm_medium=tekstlink&utm_content=siteheader&utm_campaign=Optimalisatie', 'https://www.volkskrant.nl/shop/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/service', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/cultuur-en-leven/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/agenda/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/recensies/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/film/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/muziek/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/reizen/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/koken-en-eten/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/theater/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/boeken/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/beeldende-kunst/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/leven/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mode-en-mooi/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/festivals/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/televisie/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/voordeel/', 'http://volkskrant.kranten.nl/?utm_source=volkskrant.nl&utm_medium=tekstlink&utm_content=siteheader&utm_campaign=Optimalisatie', 'https://www.volkskrant.nl/shop/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/service', '#mijn-volkskrant-subnav', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/nieuws/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/ik-volg/onderwerpen/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/lees-later/', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/instellingen/', '#logout', '#login', '#login', '#login', '#login', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/mijn-vk/instellingen/', '#logout', 'https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/', 'https://twitter.com/twitterapi', '#', '#', '#', '#', 'http://twitter.com/share?url=', 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=', 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=', 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=', '/modal.do?componentId=&secondaryComponentId=&componentType=', '#', '#', '#login', '#login', 'http://abonnement.volkskrant.nl/productinformatie?otag=9f8ydb&utm_source=vk&utm_medium=tekstlink&utm_content=tekstlink+footer&utm_campaign=vk+info', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/static/nmc/nmc/cookiewet/scherm4.html?20140314', '#', 'http://www.volkskrant.nl/static/nmc/nmc/cookiewet/scherm4.html?20140314']
```

It would get the value of all the href attribute present in all the anchor tags.

Comment: to get the links which starts with `http`, `[i['href'] for i in soup.find_all('a', href=True) if i['href'].startswith('http')]`